# How can i view all the state for NEAR blockchain and respectively for arbitrary smart contract and prove some value takes part in calculation root

Tags: blockchain, proof, nearprotocol

I want to prove that some value that is stored in smart contract on Near is takes part of calcualtion in whole blockchain state root.

I have found the view-state function that odes the job of the contract level and generates proof for that.

```
http post https://rpc.mainnet.near.org jsonrpc=2.0 id=dontcare method=query \
params:='{
"request_type": "view_state",
"finality": "final",
"account_id": "prover.bridge.near",
"prefix_base64": "",
"include_proof": true
}'
```

So now i need "view-whole-blockcahin" type of function with proofs of merkle trees. I hope the task is obvious and thnx for the response in advance